# Connecting to MySQL from Laravel vagrant box

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, sequelpro

I am using Sequel Pro on Mac and trying to see my database schemas that `Laravel` created. In the migrations folder I see a users and password reset tables.  I am trying to see them in `sequel pro` which I do not.

I used homestead and the vagrant box is up.  The homestead.yaml is set to defaults to:

```
IP: 192.168.10.10
MySQL db: homestead
```

In the .env file I see the defaults too:

```
IP: 127.0.0.1
MySQL: homestead
User: homestead
Password: secret
```

I try to use both IP's but can't seem to connect and if I do connect with 192.168.10.10 I see 0 tables. What am I missing? New to `Vagrant` and `Laravel` too.

Comment: Have you (1) set up the `.env` file, and then run `php artisan migrate` in your project root?

Comment: What do you mean setup the .env? I am using the defaults. I aslo used php artisan make-migration and that created a new file correctly in the proper folder so that is setup.  Do I have to do migrate to move it into the sql database? I would think it did it for me.

Comment: `make:migration` is only creating the migration scaffolds for you. You will need to call `php artisan migrate` to actually runs the scripts to modify the database. The `.env` should be created from the `.env.example` file so laravel would know how to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to declare the DB connection to

> config/databases.php

note that you can declare multiple DB connections here if you don't use `.env` for course.

then try `php artisan cache:clear`